# MouseJoint in cocos2d V3 for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I'm looking for "MouseJoints" or an equivalent in the new version of cocos2d (3.0) for iOS which use the Chipmunk physics library instead of Box2d. Is there anything like this? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For our [tutorial](https://www.makegameswith.us/tutorials/getting-started-with-spritebuilder/spritebuilder-physics/) chapter on firing a catapult by touch interaction I use a regular `CCNode` that follows the user's touches and create a joint between that Node and the catapult arm.

This sufficiently replaces a MouseJoint.

Comment: Okay thanks I will try this ! Is the performance good with this method?

Answer (score 0):

I used this is how I implemented it and posted on [rotategears blog](http://www.rotategears.com/development/cocos2d-v3-and-physics-mousejoint/).

Basically I created a sprite that represents the user input and made the sprite follow the users touch points. Make sure to remove the joint at TouchEnded.